# SQLite strftime() returning null with integers

Tags: sql, sqlite, date, strftime

I have a date with the column name "date" in my table "productions" stored as integer with Unix format ( example: 1548263300000). And I want to retrieve only the year. When I do:

```
SELECT strftime('%Y ',date) as year
FROM productions
```

it returns null.

When I change the type to TEXT into my table and I store the date in string format ( example 2020-05-01 ), the same sql returns me "2020" which is correct and what I was looking for.

Why strftime() doesn't work with integers since the [SQLite documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) say you can work with TEXT,INTEGER and REAL for dates? How to use date functions with integers?

**extra information:**

In this tutorial, they also use strftime with integers and it seems to work for them, so I understand from that, that the functions are available no matter what type you use ( text,int,real): [link](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-date/)

when I use:

```
SELECT strftime('%Y',DATETIME(ROUND(date/ 1000), 'unixepoch')) 
FROM productions;
```

it works fine, but I don't understand why I have to do all this when I use integers but when I use text, it works directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `strftime()` but you have to add the `'unixepoch'` modifier:

```
strftime('%Y', date / 1000, 'unixepoch')
```

so your `date / 1000` is recognized as the number of seconds since `1970-01-01`.

From [Date And Time Functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html):

> The "unixepoch" modifier (11) only works if it immediately follows a
>   timestring in the DDDDDDDDDD format. This modifier causes the
>   DDDDDDDDDD to be interpreted not as a Julian day number as it normally
>   would be, but as Unix Time - the number of seconds since 1970.

Comment: sorry i dont understand . Documentation say that Integers are already storing unix time https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html . so why i have to use "unix epoch" modifier if its already in that format ? Anyway, those functions are not very intuitive since SQLite documentation say thet text, integer and real are supported, but you need to use operations and modifiers for integers but not for text. Thanks for your quick answer.

Comment: There is no DATE data type in SQLite. The documentation describes the various ways that you could store a date so that it could be interpreted easily as a date say for comparisons. If you store a date as dd-mm-yyyy you can't use it directly as a date and compare it with other dates. The only valid date formats that you can use are here: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html (2. Time Strings) where **the integer represenation is not among them**, but there is the floating point. So you need the 'unixepoch' in order for the integer to be interpreted as a date.